# Командная строка: как дублировать перенаправление вывода в файл?

Tags: файлы, cmd, linux

Добрый день.

Мне нужно, чтобы вывод команды сохранился в файл и при этом использовать его дальше в конвейере. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee